# Which scripts are spinning up my hdd on start/wake?

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, suspend, power-management, wakeup

I've managed to put my HDD to sleep on wake-up with the script that contains `sudo hdparm -y /dev/sda3` and resides in **/lib/systemd/system-sleep**. But appending the same line to **~/.profile** have not helped, it goes to sleep after login and then something spinning it up again.
So I thought that I'd better prevent it from spinning up at all and the question is => *What is the proper way to tell Ubuntu to not to start my HDD or put it to sleep after login using hdparm?*

UPDATE: the OS itself is entirely on SSD :)

Comment: How long until it wakes up? An installed system is not entirely in RAM.

Comment: @user535733 sorry i forgot to mention that my system is installed entirely on SSD

Comment: SSds don't spin .. what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @SorenA my laptop has 2 driver: 1) SSD(where OS resides); 2) HDD(used for backups and huge downloads storage only). I want HDD to be in sleep all the time, not spinned down, but asleep with `hdparm command` so I can wake it up only whenn needed.

Comment: @r_metal Ahhh ok .. `UPDATE: the OS itself is entirely on SSD :)` fooled me.

Comment: It's not really about 'telling Ubuntu' not to do action X or Y. It's about discovering *why* Ubuntu is doing X or Y, then deciding if those files should be on the SSD or those processes disabled. EXAMPLE: You cannot 'tell Ubuntu' to not, say, create logfiles, but you can move logfiles to the SSD or change logfile settings.